# Is it possible to echo out the column(s) that are updated when UPDATING the db?

Tags: php

When I update a row in my db using these codes below:

```
if ($stmt=$conn->prepare("UPDATE db SET col1=?,col2=? WHERE id = ?")) {
  $stmt->bind_param("sss",$col1,$col2,$id);
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->close();
}
```

Is it possible to know/ print out the column(s) that are being updated?

I was thinking to use this function `isset()` but maybe there's a better way for this

Comment: Not totally clear what you mean! Do you want to know if the new values you are placing in these 2 columns are actually different to the values that were there before? OR Just that you attempted to update col1 and col2. Neither is impossible but you will have to write more code, there is nothing Auto-Magical that will do it for you

Comment: Just a note - is there any reason why you are not binding the `$data_id`?

Comment: I think that both columns will be affected although the variables were empty. You can use echo $col1 + ' ' + $col2. Moreover you can see the num of rows afected with $stmt->affected_rows.

Comment: @sochas, you have the wrong concatenation character, this aint JS, its hould be a dot.

Comment: @delboy1978uk you are right :)

Comment: @NigelRen yes, sorry about that... binding it now. Thank you

Comment: @RiggsFolly - When I successfully updated the row... I wanted to show what column was affected by the update

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend echoing, and instead suggest you just `error_log()` it and just check your log from the terminal, but I don't see what problem you could possibly be having? Also, bind the ID too!

```
if ($stmt=$conn->prepare("UPDATE db SET col1=?,col2=? WHERE id =?")) {

  error_log('Col 1 is ' . $col1 . ', Col 2 is ' . $col2); // or...
  echo 'Coll 1 is ' . $col1 . ', Col 2 is ' . $col2 . '<br />';

  $stmt->bind_param("sss", $col1, $col2, $data_id);
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: I was wrong, there is something Auto-Magical that will do it for you. :)